# codeigniter3 controller to controller functions

Tags: codeigniter, controller, view

Okay, so i have pages controller and user_authenticator controller.

pages controller is like a terminal to my views whilst the user_authenticator controller does the functions that relates to users like registration/logging in.

Whenever i'm done with a function in user_authenticator say for example logging in, how do i load the views via pages controller?

Login->user_auth(controller)->acc_model(model)->user_auth(controller)->view.

to

Login->user_auth->acc_model->pages(controller)->view.

It would be a boon for me if you guys can tell me if what i'm doing is impractical and a better way to do things. Or maybe i should just stick to loading views on the controller i used previously.

EDIT: so i may have forgotten the purpose of my pages controller but i remembered due to a moment of clarity from my foggy and tired mind.

I made a pages controller solely to load views, i guess in a sense, pages won't be loading ALL view but atleast most of the views, for example, if i had links in my views to other views, i would link them via the pages.

For specific functions that need specific controllers i guess i can let them handle loading some views.

Then again, if someone could tell me what i'm doing is a waste of time and should just delete pages controller please tell me so, i'd like to know why.

also if you have any suggestions for further uses of my pages controller thatd be great!

Also regarding session. I have a base controller.

```
    <?php
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function is_logged_in($data){    
        $session = $this->session->userdata();
        if($session['isloggedin']['username'] == ''){ 
        return isset($session); 
        }else{ 
        return FALSE;}  
    }
}
?>
```

How do i make it so that it automatically runs and checks for every controller i load if there are any session set?

Do i have to put it into a constructor? or do i have to call the base controller method from all controllers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the best solution for you.
You can use Hooks
Step1:
application/config/config.php

```
    $config['enable_hooks'] = TRUE;//enable hook
```

Step2:
application/config/hooks.php

```
    $is_logged_in= array();
    $is_logged_in['class'] = '';
    $is_logged_in['function'] = 'is_logged_in';//which function will be executed
    $is_logged_in['filename'] = 'is_logged_in.php';//hook file name
    $is_logged_in['filepath'] = 'hooks';//path.. default
    $is_logged_in['params'] = array();
    $hook['post_controller_constructor'][] = $is_logged_in;//here we decare a hook . 
    //the hook will be executed after CI_Controller construct. 
    //(also u can execute it at other time , see the CI document)
```

Step3:
application/hooks/is_logged_in.php //what u decared

```
    <?php
    //this function will be called after CI controller construct!
    function is_logged_in(){
        $ci =& get_instance();//here we get the CI super object    
        $session = $ci->session->userdata();//get session
        if($session['isloggedin']){ //if is logged in = true
             $ci->username = 'mike';//do what you want just like in controller.
             //but use $ci instead of $this**
        }else{ 
            //if not loggedin .do anything you want
            redirect('login');//go to login page.
        }  
    }
```

Step4:application/controller/pages.php

```
    <?php
    class pages extends CI_Controller{
        function construct ........
        function index(){
            echo $this->username;//it will output 'Mike', what u declared in hook
        }
    }
```

Hope it will help u.

Comment: Not exactly the answer i was looking for but then again, i already solved the problem via using extends to MY_Controller and using the constructor.